# Mongoid and UTF-8 issues in a JRuby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, jruby, mongoid, foursquare

I'm taking a JSON string that's the result from polling the Foursquare venue API:

```
{
    "id"=>"4e404742c65b4ec27606deb4",
    "name"=>"Sarah's Cheesecake & Cafe",
    "contact"=>{
        "phone"=>"4134436678",
        "formattedPhone"=>"(413) 443-6678"
    },
    "location"=>{
        "address"=>"180 Elm St",
        "lat"=>42.44345873,
        "lng"=>-73.23804678,
        "distance"=>1063,
        "postalCode"=>"01201",
        "city"=>"Pittsfield",
        "state"=>"MA"
    },
    "categories"=>[
        {
            "id"=>"4bf58dd8d48988d16d941735",
            "name"=>"Café",
            "pluralName"=>"Cafés",
            "shortName"=>"Café",
            "icon"=>{
                "prefix"=>"https://foursquare.com/img/categories/food/cafe_",
                "sizes"=>[
                    32,
                    44,
                    64,
                    88,
                    256
                ],
                "name"=>".png"
            },
            "primary"=>true
        }
    ],
    "verified"=>false,
    "stats"=>{
        "checkinsCount"=>7,
        "usersCount"=>5,
        "tipCount"=>0
    },
    "hereNow"=>{
        "count"=>0
    }
}
```

As you can tell, there are some non-standard characters in there such as `Cafés` and that's breaking my Mongoid based Model in this JRuby on Rails app. When trying to to create an instance with MyModel.create, here's what I get.

```
jruby-1.6.5 :012 > FoursquareVenue.create(hash)
Java::JavaLang::NullPointerException: 
    from org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException.<init>(RaiseException.java:101)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.newRaiseException(Ruby.java:3348)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.newEncodingCompatibilityError(Ruby.java:3323)
    from org.jruby.RubyString.cat(RubyString.java:1285)
    from org.jruby.RubyString.cat19(RubyString.java:1221)
    from org.jruby.RubyHash$5.visit(RubyHash.java:727)
    from org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:594)
    from org.jruby.RubyHash.inspectHash(RubyHash.java:721)
    from org.jruby.RubyHash.inspect(RubyHash.java:745)
    from org.jruby.RubyHash$i$0$0$inspect.call(RubyHash$i$0$0$inspect.gen:65535)
    from org.jruby.RubyClass.finvoke(RubyClass.java:632)
    from org.jruby.javasupport.util.RuntimeHelpers.invoke(RuntimeHelpers.java:545)
    from org.jruby.RubyBasicObject.callMethod(RubyBasicObject.java:353)
    from org.jruby.RubyObject.inspect(RubyObject.java:408)
    from org.jruby.RubyArray.inspectAry(RubyArray.java:1483)
    from org.jruby.RubyArray.inspect(RubyArray.java:1509)
... 420 levels...
    from org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:75)
    from org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:190)
    from org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:179)
    from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:312)
    from org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:169)
    from usr.local.rvm.rubies.jruby_minus_1_dot_6_dot_5.bin.jirb.__file__(/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/bin/jirb:17)
    from usr.local.rvm.rubies.jruby_minus_1_dot_6_dot_5.bin.jirb.load(/usr/local/rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.5/bin/jirb)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:693)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.runScript(Ruby.java:686)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.runNormally(Ruby.java:593)
    from org.jruby.Ruby.runFromMain(Ruby.java:442)
    from org.jruby.Main.doRunFromMain(Main.java:321)
    from org.jruby.Main.internalRun(Main.java:241)
    from org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:207)
    from org.jruby.Main.run(Main.java:191)
    from org.jruby.Main.main(Main.java:171)
```

If I strip out all the odd characters, everything works as expected and no exception is thrown. What's the proper way of handling this? Can I enabled my Mongoid/MongoDB documents to work with UTF-8? do I need to "asciify" them somehow first if that's not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Could be an encoding bug in JRuby's 1.9 mode. Does the same thing happen when you run it in 1.8 mode? Either way, a stacktrace should be filed as a bug at http://bugs.jruby.org. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nick, I'm running everything in 1.8 mode still: jruby 1.6.5 (ruby-1.8.7-p330) (2011-10-25 9dcd388) (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 1.6.0_20) [linux-amd64-java]

Answer (score 0):

`gem install bson_ext` might help.

Source: [MongoDB, Ruby and UTF-8](http://wellconsidered.be/post/10519709846/mongodb-ruby-and-utf-8)

If you are using ubuntu, then you need to do some extra steps with spidermonkey/mongodb installation:

> Most pre-built Javascript SpiderMonkey libraries do not have UTF-8
>   support compiled in; MongoDB requires this.

Source: [Building for Linux](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Building+for+Linux)

Comment: Nope, this is reproducible on both my prod environment (RHEL) and staging (OSX Lion)

Comment: In the both the installation scenarios, while installing mongodb, you need to be sure to mark -utf-8 enabled.

Comment: Actually I take that back. This is not reproducible on OSX anymore. Only on my RHEL box. Using the same exact gem set.

Comment: Then try to follow the instructions documented above, that might be the issue.

Comment: I am using a prebuilt binary supplied by 10gen. Don't really see a reason to compile my own. Is there a way to check if the precompiled binary has utf-8 support built into it?

Comment: That's the problem. The documentation clearly says that: `Most pre-built Javascript SpiderMonkey libraries do not have UTF-8 support compiled in; MongoDB requires this`. So the you need to build it manually by following the guidelines mentioned in the above link.

Comment: Unfortunately I've recompiled SpiderMonkey with UTF-8 enabled and compiled MongoDB. no luck though, same encoding issue.

Comment: Still think there is something going on outside of MongoDB. Although it's only reproducible on my RHEL box and not on my OSX devel box, I can insert UTF-8 strings into the mongo client. Just not via irb.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB and mongoid handle utf-8 properly. I was doing the same thing with the Foursquare API not long ago via the Quimby wrapper.

As a result, I would suspect the bug is closely related to the use of JRuby.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up JRuby to use UTF8?

```
require 'jcode'
$KCODE = 'u'
```